# How to know who is the parent in a Grails hasMany relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many

We have an old application where the relationship is defined as below:

```
class Practice {
   String name
   static hasmany = [doctors:Doctor]
}
```

and

```
class Doctor {
  String name
}
```

There is not a `belongsTo` relationship defined in `Doctor` as we do not want to cascade the delete of a doctor when `Practice` is deleted. This is a very old code and do not want to change it.

Now according to the new functionality, the user should know which `Practice`s the `Doctor` is linked to while viewing the details of a `Doctor`. Can anyone help me knowing which is the easiest way of achieving this without making changes to the domain object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If variable `doctor` contains the doctor you want to list practices from, you can get a list of `Practice` objects having this doctor in their doctors relationship by issuing the following criteria query:

```
def practices = Practice.withCriteria {
  doctors {
    idEq(doctor.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was simple. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Just for record

```
def practices = Practice.withCriteria {
  doctors {
    eq("id",doctor.id)
  }
}
```